# Hibernate cache error when generate the jhipster-multitenancy application with Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I use the jhipster-generator v4.13.1 in order to generate the main jhipster application. After that I use the command

```
`npm install generator-jhipster-multitenancy`
```

in order to install the multitenancy generator.

The problems occourse when I try to do `yo jhipster-multitenancy`, a prompt is given with What is the alias given tenants in your application? (Company) after I press enter in this situation the next error occours

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: /home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/generator-jhipster-multitenancy/generators/app/templates/src/main/java/package/domain/_User.java:26
    24| import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    25| import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;<% if (databaseType === 'sql') { %>
 >> 26| import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize;<% } %><% if (hibernateCache !== 'no' && databaseType === 'sql') { %>
    27| import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
    28| import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;<% } %>
    29| import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;

hibernateCache is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:28:8)
    at returnedFn (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
    at Object.exports.render (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:384:37)
    at process (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy-tpl.js:12:18)
    at applyProcessingFunc (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy.js:13:16)
    at EditionInterface.exports._copySingle (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy.js:63:16)
    at files.forEach.file (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy.js:50:10)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EditionInterface.exports.copy (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/lib/actions/copy.js:49:9)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as copyTpl] (/home/joag/Proyectos/Munkys/prueba2/node_modules/mem-fs-ed
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. We'll get on it this week.

Answer (score 2):

It's because we change the configuration `hibernateCache` to `cacheProvider` and `enableHibernateCache`. You should open an issue in this project to inform the author, so maybe he can fix it and make a new release.